# Ubuntu 20.04 - Google Chromium is slow after wake from sleep

Tags: chromium, 20.04

As the title says, if I close my laptop lid while Chromium is running and then open it again, Chromium is quite sluggish (slow) when my laptop wakes from sleep. The mouse lags and scrolling is choppy. Other programs seem to not suffer this problem. Restarting Chromium returns it to normal. Machine is Lenovo 81SS, AMD Ryzen5 3500U.

This did not happen with Ubuntu 19.10

Thank You

Comment: The same issue with Google Chrome, everything seems laggy and glitchy display

Answer (score 8):

Same problem for me (ubuntu 20.04 + Chrome 85.0.4183.102). I solved it by simple disabling the *Use hardware acceleration when available* in Chrome Settings. There you go for a pretty long [explanation](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Google-Chrome-so-slow-to-response-on-Ubuntu) of the reasons.